# How to write Conditional Update Query Using Bookshelf.js?

Tags: mysql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have Mysql query which updates the multiple record at the same time

```
UPDATE Settings
SET value = (case when property_Name = 'p1' then 'updated p1'
                     when property_Name = 'p2' then 'updated p2'
                     when property_Name = 'p3' then 'updated p3'
                end)
WHERE property_Name in ('p1', 'p2', 'p3') AND vendor_Id = 5;
```

How do I write case in update query using Bookshelf.js / knex  ?

One way is to write whole query in

```
knex.raw('UPDATE Settings
    SET value = (case when property_Name = 'p1' then 'updated p1'
                         when property_Name = 'p2' then 'updated p2'
                         when property_Name = 'p3' then 'updated p3'
                    end)
    WHERE property_Name in ('p1', 'p2', 'p3') AND vendor_Id = 5;');
```

is there any other way to write query using Bookshelf.js (avoiding knex.raw())?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about how to avoid *knex*, but you don't need the case statement.

```
knex.raw('UPDATE Settings
    SET value = CONCAT('updated ',property_Name)
    WHERE property_Name in ('p1', 'p2', 'p3') AND vendor_Id = 5;');
```

Comment: I will require the case statements because there can be multiple property_Name 
 update and value can be any string.